How to create a listView when you click on a button
I am looking for help .... how to fix this problem.
I try to create a App to display a list of informations when you click a button.
If the list is to be displayed on the same layout than the calling button, there is no problem and it works.
But ...
If the list is to be displayed on a new layout, it will not work, the listView layout is not displayed and the App terminates without message.
I tried many examples of code coming from the web but no one works. I suspect a configuration of my Android Studio software.
I am using : Android Studio jelly fish, Java, Sdk platform API 30, emulator using pixel 4 Api 30.
here is an abstract of my code showing the MainActivity and the ListViewActivity  that poses a problem
here is the code:
MainActivity
package fr.yodrack.simplelistview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });


        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Lancer la nouvelle activité
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

Activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>





package fr.yodrack.simplelistview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

        // Création des données à afficher dans la ListView
        ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataList.add("Élément 1");
        dataList.add("Élément 2");
        dataList.add("Élément 3");

        // Création de l'adaptateur pour la ListView
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataList);

        // Récupération de la ListView
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // Association de l'adaptateur à la ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}



activity_listview.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>




 


The issue is you are trying to access the view that are not present in activities. Update your xml as below.
Activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp" />
    
</RelativeLayout>

activity_listview.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    tools:context=".ListViewActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Also make sure the ListViewActivity is defined in Android Manifest file.
